# Помогите подключить кнопку поделиться Вконтакте в приложение, используя библиотеку ASNE

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api, share

Никак у меня не получается следуя статье https://habrahabr.ru/post/237095/ подключить возможность делиться в ВК. В статье, как я понимаю описано много того, что мне не нужно. А у меня ситуация такая. В определенный момент в игре выскакивает DialogFragment и на нём кнопка Vk, по нажатию на которую должна опубликоваться запись на стене в ВК. Приложение на сайте ВК я создал, id приложения есть и библиотеку 'com.github.asne:asne-vk:0.3.3.3' я подключил, в манифест добавил разрешение на интернет. 
Последовательно мои вопросы таковы:

1) После нажатия на кнопку поделиться обычно на экране появляется Fragment, в котором следует описать то что будет публиковаться. Так ведь? но я могу просто вывести Toast с записью о том что всё прошло успешно или нет? И из этого я делаю вывод что мне из дополнительных layoutов , мне понадобится один dialogfragment и то если я не использую вместо него Toast.

2) По нажатию на кнопку Поделиться должна пройти авторизация и в случае успеха публикация. А нужно ли мне , если я использую библиотеку ASNE , создать layout для случая, когда пользователь должен ввести свои логин и пароль?

3) Покажите пожалуйста (можно скопировать из статьи) код, который отвечает непосредственно за авторизацию.

Помогите последовательно решить проблемы, которые возникнут по ходу решения этой задачи. Пока я не знаю с чего начать. Библиотеку предлагает для удобства добавления множества Социальных сетей использовать

```
static SocialNetworkManager mSocialNetworkManager;   mSocialNetworkManager = (SocialNetworkManager) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(SOCIAL_NETWORK_TAG);
```

Я прописал эту строку в классе наследуемом от DialogFragment в методе onCreateDialog и получил ошибку о том что типы не конвертируемы, а именно android.app.Fragment с SocialNetworkManager.